# duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/SupportErrorDialogFragment.class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am creating project in android studio with multi dex support . I am getting error : java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/SupportErrorDialogFragment.class . I know this issue is for duplicate class. But unable to figure out that which class is getting duplicate and how to fix it. Below are the code of my build.gradle. Please suggest. Thanks.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rtpl.create.app.v2"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':pageIndicator')
    compile project(':materialDesign')
    compile project(':zxingLib')
    compile project(':datetimepickerlibrary')
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/Android_SDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/Android_SDK_component.jar')
    compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/im.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/linkedin-j-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/PayPal_MECL.jar')
    compile files('libs/prime-0.6.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/socialauth-4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/socialauth-android-2.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1-SNAPSHOT-with-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have conflicting dependencies in your build.gradle, meaning multiple dependencies containing the same classes:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
```

All of these components are provided by Google Play Services (the first one in the list). So you should only declare Google Play Services once, preferably only the components you're using instead of the full package: See "Selectively compiling APIs into your executable" https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Chances are you won't even need multidex after you simplify your project dependencies.

Also (unrelated), I'm wondering what are these dependencies, if it's the Android framework itself you can remove them:

```
compile files('libs/Android_SDK.jar')
compile files('libs/Android_SDK_component.jar')
```

Comment: Thanks, its work for me. I have removed all above dependency and added individuals only, also removed Android dependency its working now. Thank you.